# Relative path to import unmanaged DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I want to import a C++ DLL in my C# code.

It works great using an absolute path pointing directly to this library, but I can't make it works using a relative path.

The code that works is :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[...]

[DllImport(@"C:\full\path\to\LibraryName.dll",
                EntryPoint = "?export@symbol",
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern IntPtr functionName(string param);
```

Note that I don't have a Visual Studio project to use and add references to. I am just adding a functionality to an existing (and working) .NET application by adding a new .aspx.cs page which is called somewhere within the app via the corresponding .aspx page.

The application is currently deployed on IIS 7.5 hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

This may be a duplicate of these issues, but it didn't work for me. : [Relative path to unmanaged DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256901/relative-path-to-unmanaged-dll)
[How can I specify a [DllImport] path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime)

Any new ideas compared to the posts mentioned above ?

Comment: Double check your working directory: It is typically set to the project folder and not the binary folder. Though because the working directory is relatively volatile, I do not like this method of linking.

Comment: It would be much easier to spot an error if you'd publish the version which does not work. As it stands one has to guess what you wrote and then explain why it does not work, which is a bit difficult.

Comment: What happens when you use `SetDllDirectory`?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Get Full Path Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)?  I'm not sure if it would work for a dll file, but it's worth a shot.